# Entity Framework - pessimistic locking

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

What I am trying to do is basically [what NHibernate does](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and-concurrency#10%282E%296%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Pessimistic_Locking) when you do something like:

```
var instance = session.Get<Customer>(id, LockMode.Upgrade);
```

I need to lock the entity row in the database. Why I need that? 
Imagine something like a workflow instance that can be updated by multiple actors(people or processes) at the same time.

The constraints I have don't allow for optimistic locking solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF doesn't have support for this. If you want to lock some record by query you must do something like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
{
    using (var context = new YourContext(...))
    {
        var customer = 
            context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Customer>("SELECT ... FROM Customers WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ...");

        // rest of your logic while record is locked

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Or `context.Database.SqlQuery` in case of DbContext API.

Answer (score 1):

You could also move your SQL Code to EDMX storage model, if you don't want to have plain SQL in your C# Code (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd296754%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
<Function Name="LockTestTable" IsComposable="false">
    <CommandText>
        SELECT NULL
        FROM TestTable WITH (UPDLOCK)
        WHERE TestTableID = @testTableID
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="testTableID"
        Mode="In"
        Type="int" />
</Function>
```

And call it like this

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
{
    using (var context = new YourContext(...))
    {
        context.LockTestTable(1);

        // Record locked

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```